# JSON encode data from MySQL results

Tags: php, mysql, json

I get no data from menucanhan.php?type=view. Is it something wrong with my code? Plz, help me check it! Thanks too much!

db.php: proceed data from localhost

```
<?php
class DB {
    // Database credentials
    private $dbHost     = 'localhost';
    private $dbUsername = 'root';
    private $dbPassword = '';
    private $dbName     = 'thuctapcoso';
    public $db;

    public function __construct(){
        if(!isset($this->db)){
            // Connect to the database
            try{
                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->dbHost.";dbname=".$this->dbName, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword);
                $conn -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $this->db = $conn;
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                die("Failed to connect with MySQL: " . $e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public function getRows($table,$conditions = array()){
        $sql = 'SELECT ';
        $sql .= array_key_exists("select",$conditions)?$conditions['select']:'*';
        $sql .= ' FROM '.$table;
        if(array_key_exists("where",$conditions)){
            $sql .= ' WHERE ';
            $i = 0;
            foreach($conditions['where'] as $key => $value){
                $pre = ($i > 0)?' AND ':'';
                $sql .= $pre.$key." = '".$value."'";
                $i++;
            }
        }

        if(array_key_exists("order_by",$conditions)){
            $sql .= ' ORDER BY '.$conditions['order_by']; 
        }

        if(array_key_exists("start",$conditions) && array_key_exists("limit",$conditions)){
            $sql .= ' LIMIT '.$conditions['start'].','.$conditions['limit']; 
        }elseif(!array_key_exists("start",$conditions) && array_key_exists("limit",$conditions)){
            $sql .= ' LIMIT '.$conditions['limit']; 
        }

        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();

        if(array_key_exists("return_type",$conditions) && $conditions['return_type'] != 'all'){
            switch($conditions['return_type']){
                case 'count':
                    $data = $query->rowCount();
                    break;
                case 'single':
                    $data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    break;
                default:
                    $data = '';
            }
        }else{
            if($query->rowCount() > 0){
                $data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }
        }

        return !empty($data)?$data:false;
    }
}
?>
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

menucanhan.php:

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
$db = new DB();
$tblName = 'menucanhan';
if(isset($_REQUEST['type']) && !empty($_REQUEST['type'])){
    $type = $_REQUEST['type'];
    switch($type){
        case "view":
            $records = $db->getRows($tblName);
            if($records){
                $data['records'] = $db->getRows($tblName);  
                $data['status'] = 'OK';
            }else{
                $data['records'] = array();
                $data['status'] = 'ERR';
            }
            echo json_encode($data);
            break;        
        default:
            echo '{"status":"INVALID"}';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You should start by doing some broad debugging.  Echo bits of data at different points in the flow and isolate where the problems are versus what is working as expected.

Comment: Try echo the sql statement in the getRows function

Comment: Verify the table is not empty as your function only returns when a row exists

Comment: If you really wrote that class,  you should be able to debug it easily

Comment: You should make better use of your PDO call and use placeholders to protect your queries from injection attacks.

Comment: I must say, this looks suspect: `$records = $db->getRows($tblName);
            if($records){
                $data['records'] = $db->getRows($tblName);`   ...calling `getRows()` twice can't be right.

Comment: this code give me data: `foreach ($data['records'] as $key => $value) {
                    foreach ($value as $key => $v) {
                        echo $v;
                    }
                }` ... but `echo json_encode($data);` still not working